# How to trim an audio/video file from start and end in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: audio, video-editing, ubuntu

I've an audio and a video file, both of 3 hrs duration. I want to remove 1st 5 minutes from the beginning and last 10 minutes from the end.

How to achieve this?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18444194/cutting-the-videos-based-on-start-and-end-time-using-ffmpeg) for a cli based approach.

Comment: If you want not to recode, but copy video and audio input, and do not mind about the output container, you might use `mkvmerge`from the `mkvtoolnix`package. This allows to split videos (`mkvmerge --split parts:`), see https://mkvtoolnix.download/doc/mkvmerge.html.